# ASP.NET / MVC4 Connection String to SQL Server 2008 error

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working through an ASP.NET MVC4 tutorial from ASP.net.  This is the second tutorial in which I am getting database connection errors.  Here is the error:

> An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity >Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that >the connection string is correct.

Here are my connection strings.  The first one was generated by the template, the 2nd was copied verbatim from the tutorial.  I am running SQL Server 2008, not express.  That may be my problem.  The database is created automatically from the application as well.  I do not have a login / password that I am aware of for this local db.

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcMovie-20130830102032;Integrated Security=SSPI" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="MovieDBContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I've looked on connectionstrings.com & asp.net to find a resolution and I am not clear on the fix.  The error has to be in the connection string, but I am unsure which one, if not both, it is.

Thanks

I just changed the data source to Data Source=. and here is the error now:

```
There is already an object named 'PK_dbo.Movies' in the database.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

I tried to delete the database in sql server and was unable to when right clicking on it and pressing delete.  Any ideas?

Comment: If you're **not** using Express, then most likely, the `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS` is just plain wrong. Is your SQL Server 2008 the **default** instance (without an instance name)?? If so, just use `Data Source=.` instead

Comment: Neither one of these is an EntityFramework connection string.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnection.connectionstring.aspx